# Npm issue installing Ionic

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

I have an issue with installing one package with NPM.

Here is what I type in in the console, and the outcome:

```
MacBook:folder Uksz$ sudo npm install ionic -g
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic

> node-sass@3.4.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

sh: node: command not found
npm WARN install:node-sass node-sass@3.4.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN install:node-sass spawn ENOENT

> spawn-sync@1.0.14 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall

sh: node: command not found
npm WARN install:spawn-sync spawn-sync@1.0.14 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm WARN install:spawn-sync spawn ENOENT
/usr/local/lib
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
```

I was wondering if you guys have any ideas on how I can fix that?

Thanks
uksz

EDIT:

My Node is v5.0.0, and npm v3.3.6